# Assigning a GPO to a computer?

Tags: group-policy

I have a sales area with 30 Computers in it. The Employee turn over is very high and I was tired of setting multiple users up everyday. I made a Sale1 logon and am having all 30 Computers use it. The only problem I have ran into is I have 2 Different sizes of monitors at the res of 1280x1024, 1366x768. In the GPO I assign a Desktop background and set it on stretch so one type of monitor graphics always looks Bad. I tried to link two GPO's with the correct Backgrounds in each of them and assign them to the correct computers. It seems that whatever GPO is in 1st link place that's what it gives everyone. Does anyone have any ideas I can try to correct this.

Thanks You,

Comment: Why not set up Sale1, Sale2, etc?

Comment: Just don't set your background to stretch?

Comment: or try some variation of 'wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight/screenwidth' adjust accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way might be to use security filtering on the appropriate polices so they only apply to the correct computers.

Create two AD groups, put the computers in the correct groups, and use filtering on the appropriate polices to apply the policies only to the correct groups.

If you don't want to go this route, you could always separate the computers by OU and apply the appropriate policies to the matching OU.